# How to only read first child?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to only read the first piece of data from a ref that gets its data from `.push()` insertions. Is there a way to only get the first piece of data when I don't necessarily know its key?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming JavaScript, you can do:

```
ref.orderByKey().limitToFirst(1).once('value', function(snap) {
  snap.val(); // first item, in format {"<KEY>": "<VALUE>"}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store the newly received data from the ref in something (var or object or array) and get it with `console.log(wateverArray[0])`